# Trying to check fields which are blank according to fields that have a specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check fields which are blank according to fields that have a specified class, this is my code below:

```
function hasBlanks() {
    var blanks = new Array();
    $(".required").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") 
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** (Added based on OP comment) Basically, the code isn't working as planned. How can I check fields which are blank that hold a specified class?

Comment: Basically, the code isn't working as planned. How can I check fields which are blank that hold a specified class?

Comment: *How* is the code not working? Does it have false positives? False negatives?

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigned and returning the array for matched elements. you can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the criteria.

```
emptyFields = $(".required").filter(function(){
      return $(this).val() == "";
});
```

You code could be changed to return blank array.

```
function hasBlanks() {
    var blanks = new Array();
    $(".required").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") 
            blanks.push($this);
     });
    return blanks;
}
```

Comment: this.value ($(this).val()) $.trim is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasBlanks(){

    $(".required").each(function (){
        var hasBlanks = 0;
        var el = $(this).val();
        if($.trim(el) == ""){
           hasBlanks++;
        }
    });

    if (hasBlanks > 0) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```